# Is there a difference between using reportViewer in winforms vs windowsformshost

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, reportviewer, windowsformshost

new to visual studio and cant figure out the difference. In my project if I try to do winformshost the reportviewer doesn't show up in my toolbox. If I do new winforms item it does show in toolbox. Looking for some much needed guidance.

Comment: That is normal, the toolbox can only display WPF controls so point-and-click can no longer work.  A step-by-step guide [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx)

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Thank you I will try that.